# How to detect when mouse stops moving in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

I'm trying to dynamically toggle the visibility of a button element based on mouse movement (i.e., `{visibility: visible}` when the mouse is moving, `{visibility: hidden}` when it stops moving). The button is showing with onMouseMove, but I'm struggling with where to start on the second part. Since React doesn't have an `onMouseStop` event, what's the best way to achieve this?

```
export default class Infographic extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      mouseMoving: false,
    };

    this.setMouseMove = this.setMouseMove.bind(this);
  }

  setMouseMove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({mouseMoving: true});
  }

  render() {

    const scrollButtonStyle = {
      visibility: this.state.mouseMoving ? 'visible': 'hidden', 
     };

     return (
       <div onMouseMove={e => this.setMouseMove(e)}>
         <button style={scrollButtonStyle}>Back to top</button>
         <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
       </div>  
     );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Per the suggestions below, I added the following IIFE block to the setMouseMove method (using arrow functions for scope access) and it works just as expected. Thanks for the help!

```
setMouseMove(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({mouseMoving: true});

  let timeout;
  (() => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => this.setState({mouseMoving:false}), 50);
  })();
}
```

Comment: You'll have to set up a timer that sets `mouseMoving` to `false` when no `mousemove` events have been received for some amount of time.

Answer (score 7):

Have a timeout function that sets how many milliseconds of inactivity counts as "not moving".

```
let timeout;
let whenMouseMoves = () => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(toggleButton(), 50);
}
```

And adjust the function as you see fit for your button. Obviously, you'll need to make the `toggleButton()` function if you use this code.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. Modified my original to reflect my working update.

Comment: YW. Make sure to vote my questions as "best answer" if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: I did! I just don't have enough reputation points for it to be recorded. Will be sure to come back and do so once I do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Your code helped me implement a feature in my portfolio which hides the menus after some seconds without mouse movement.

However, I came across a bug: when moving the mouse continuously, the menu was starting to blink or disappearing before the set timeout (which was 2.5 seconds).

To anyone who uses this approach and are encountering the same bug I'm about to describe, I was able to solve it (sort of).

The issue is that every time you move the mouse, the `setMouseMove()` will trigger, and the `clearTimeout()` will not clear the `setTimeout()` that was triggered the last time the mouse moved. This is because `setMouseMove()` is again declaring the `timeout` variable, which will be now empty, and then when the code gets to `clearTimeout()`, the `timeout = setTimeout()` was not yet triggered.

To solve this issue, I created a variable called `enableMoving`, used a `setInterval()` of 2500s (to match my `setTimeout()` interval) to set `enableMoving` to `true`, and on `setMouseMove()` -> `setTimeout()` I put a condition to check and stop the function if `enableMoving` is `false`, otherwise the code runs and set `enableMoving` to `false`.

That way, `setTimeout()` will only trigger if `enableMoving` is true (which will be every 2.5 seconds).

This is the code for better understanding:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      mouseMoving: false,
    }

    this.state = {
      enableMove: true,
    }

    this.setMouseMove = this.setMouseMove.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({enableMove: true})
    }, 2500)
  }
    
  setMouseMove(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({mouseMoving: true})

    const time = 2500
    let timeout
    (() => {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.state.enableMove === false) return 0
        this.setState({mouseMoving: false})
        this.setState({enableMove: false})
      }, time)   
    })();
  }

  render() {

    const isVisible = {
      opacity: this.state.mouseMoving ? 1 : 0,
    }

  return ( [...rest of the code...] )

  }
}
```

I said this "sort of" solved the problem, because sometimes the two timers (`setInterval()` and `setTimeout()`) does not sync together and the menu will disappear slightly before 2.5 seconds, but is much more precise and stable than before.

Perhaps if you play with both timers a little bit you will get to a better result.